# How can I insert multiple dynamically checkbox value in insert?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

when i insert this form all field is inserted but the problem is multiple checkbox value is not insert?

This is my HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">    

    <?php
        $j=3;

        for($i=0;$i< $j; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            First name :: <input name="firstname[]" type="text" value=""/><br>
            <input name="loop" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $j ?>"/>
            Last name :: <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="" /><br>
            Age :: <input name="age[]" type="text" value="" /><br>
            <input name="hobbey[]" type="checkbox" value="Cricket" />Cricket
            <input name="hobbey[]" type="checkbox" value="Football" />Football
            <input name="hobbey[]" type="checkbox" value="Tennis" />Tennis
            <br><br>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

    <input name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
    $query = "insert into register (firstname,lastname,age,hobbey) values";

    for($i=0; $i<$_POST["loop"]; $i++)
    {
        $firstname=$_POST["firstname"][$i];
        $lastname=$_POST["lastname"][$i];
        $age=$_POST["age"][$i];

        $hobbey=$_POST["hobbey"][$i];

        $query .= "('$firstname','$lastname','$age','$hobbey')";
    }
```

Comment: because the hobby you getting at i = 0 is array

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi array on the name of the checkboxes

```
<input name="hobbey[<?php echo $i;?>][]" type="checkbox" value="Cricket" />Cricket
<input name="hobbey[<?php echo $i;?>][]" type="checkbox" value="Football" />Football
<input name="hobbey[<?php echo $i;?>][]" type="checkbox" value="Tennis" />Tennis
```

in php you do:

```
 $hobbey=implode(';',$_POST["hobbey"][$i]);
```

beware sql injection

Comment: don't forget the green check :)

Answer (score 0):

Because at the value of i = 0 you getting array of values of hobbey thats y its not inserting, try it with implode it generate a string of array and then insert that string to your table,

```
    $hobbey=$_POST["hobbey"][$i];
    $hby=implode(',',$hobbey);
    $query .= "('$firstname','$lastname','$age','$hby')";
```